# MVC LINQ: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'X'. 'Select' not found

Tags: model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

Just starting messing with repository/interfaces and the like and I have an error when selecting a single record which I can't work out.

My controller has:

```
    public ViewResult Detail(int ID)
    {
        var Details = (from x in repo.GetBreakdown(ID) select new BreakdownDetailViewModel { }).SingleOrDefault();

        return View(Details);
    }
```

The statement repo.GetBreakdown(ID) is underlined with the following error:

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type ''. 'Select' not found.
```

My Interface is showing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Domain.Entities;

namespace Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IBreakdownRepository
    {
        tblBreakdown_Log GetBreakdown(int ID);
        IQueryable<tblBreakdown_Log> GetAllBreakdowns { get; }

    }
}
```

And the repository itself has:

```
 public tblBreakdown_Log GetBreakdown(int ID)
        {
            return (from x in db.tblBreakdown_Logs where x.MB_ID == ID select x).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Any ideas on what the issue is here?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: from x in repo.GetBreakdown(ID) ?? Is tblBreakdown_Log of type IEnumerable<TSource>? from x in source, where source needs to implement IEnumerable. For your example, you should be able to do "from x in repo.GetAllBreakdowns() select.... "

Comment: Managed to fix this I think using your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @Evan

Changed my repository access to:

```
    public IEnumerable<tblBreakdown_Log> GetBreakdown(int ID)
        {
            return (from x in db.tblBreakdown_Logs where x.MB_ID == ID select x);
        }
```

The interface to the repository now has:

```
 IEnumerable<tblBreakdown_Log> GetBreakdown(int ID);
```

And my controller access is:

```
 public ViewResult Detail(int ID)
        {
        var Details = (from x in repo.GetBreakdown(ID) select new BreakdownDetailViewModel {Machine_Status=x.tblMachine_Status.Machine_Status, MB_ID=x.MB_ID});

        return View(Details);
    }
```

All working as needed now =]